# Convert following code for 3d plot in MATLAB into code for Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following 3d plot in MATLAB that I'm trying to plot in Gnuplot but don't know how to. In MATLAB, the x,y,z are matrices that are calculated inside a nested for loop, then plotted:

```
w = 50 ;
ww = 0:1:w  ;             
d = 100 ;
dd = 0:1:d  ;            

for i=1:1:length(ww)           
    for j=1:1:length(dd)       
        x(i,j) = dd(i) ;   % need to refer to array dd
        y(i,j) = dd(j) ;   
        z(i,j) = <A complicated function ommitted for simplicity>
    end                
end

plot3(x,y,z)
```

How would I plot the above in Gnuplot? I need to do it for arbitrary values of `w` and `d`. I understand that I need the `splot` function but I am at a loss as to how to implement the calculation of the x,y,z matrices. Help will be appreciated!

Edit: It seems like the above can be done using the `array` and `word` keywords/function but I haven't been able to implement it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gnuplot, simply set your ranges and plot the function:

```
set xrange [0:50]
set yrange [0:100]
z(x,y) = exp(-(x**2 + y**2)/100.0)
splot z(x, y)
```

If you want to change the grid, use `set isosamples` to do that, like

```
set isosamples 51,101
```

Comment: Holy Moly, That's so simple ;D Thanks! I got what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You could somewhat cheat, and create the gnuplot plot file from GNU Octave https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/

Assuking you have Octave installed:

Set the graphics toolkit in octave to gnuplot:

```
graphics_toolkit gnuplot
```

Then run your p[lot script.

Then dump it to a gnuplot file (assuming running in linux - in windows the x11 and /dev/null would need to change):

```
drawnow ("x11", "/dev/null", false, "gnuplot.gpt")
```

There should now be a file gnuplot.gpt that can be loaded by gnuplot - console command:

```
gnuplot -p gnuplot.gpt
```

Comment: I didn't know Octave could generate gnuplot scripts. Will try this out and get back

Comment: While I was able to generate  the plot and the gnuplot script, I need the proper gnuplot code in order to integrate it with an existing script. The code generated this way isn't proper code so I can't accept this answer.